# Pointers in C vs No pointers in PHP

Tags: php, c, pointers

Both languages have the same syntax.

Why does C have the weird `*` character that denotes pointers (which is some kind of memory address of the variable contents?), when PHP doesn't have it and you can do pretty much the same things in PHP that you can do in C, without pointers? I guess the PHP compiler handles this internally, why doesn't C do the same?

Doesn't this add unneeded complexity in C? For example I don't understand them :)

Comment: "_you can do pretty much the same things in PHP that you can do in C_" Can't tell if trolling or serious.

Comment: Couldn't one make a similar gripe about the $ character used in PHP to denote a variable?

Comment: @MahmoudHossam: If PHP is involved, then it's trolling.

Comment: Are you suggesting PHP is unworthy of respect?

Comment: @AnnaBanana he's not suggesting, he's stating a fact. :P

Comment: well, I was not trolling, I was just wondering why doesn't C handle all the memory stuff automatically, liek freeing variables from a function automatically when the function finishes execution etc. The answers explained this well - apparently it has to do with efficiency.

Comment: @AnnaBanana: It actually has more to do with pointers vs references. Google will show loads here. Google both at a time. Google them individually.

Comment: Also working with memory like pointers doesn't exactly feel "natural" in my opinion. It forces you to learn about computer internals and stuff, things not really related to programming logic

Comment: PHP references are odd too, but they can be easily replaced by using the global keyword (if you need to pass the same stuff around)

Comment: *"but they can be easily replaced by using the global keyword"* Can't tell if trolling or serious.

Comment: Where do you use PHP outside of web applications? Eventually, something has to know which bits to flip.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are use cases and advantages of pointers?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/16211/what-are-use-cases-and-advantages-of-pointers)

Comment: @AnnaBanana : Thinking that computer internals are not related at all to programming logic can lead to slow fat apps that require too much cooling or batteries to run.

Comment: @AnnaBanana "_forces you to learn about computer internals and stuff_" try writing a device driver in php or even a kernel.

Comment: @AnnaBanana: How can anyone claim that C and PHP have the same syntax? (Nomen seems to be omen in this case...)

Comment: @AnnaBanana: PHP is indeed unworthy of respect. See http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/

Comment: You *can* do the same stuff in PHP as you can in C. They're both Turing complete.

Comment: LOL @language snobbery.

Comment: @ChristianMann Don't confuse being able to perform any calculation (i.e. being Turing complete) with being able to interact with the full capabilities of a system. Sometimes, for example, you need to twiddle some bits at a very specific location in memory because the hardware demands it in order to produce the result you want. That's a wee bit difficult to do in a language with no concept of physical memory addresses.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Like so many things, the answer is of the form "Because X and Y are different things with different purposes".

In this case, the designers of both languages assumed that the users of their languages had a very different set of goals.  For C, the primary use case was "portable assembly language", which really means getting down into the nitty-gritty of how the computer is actually managing its resources.  There's no practical way to avoid memory address manipulation at the lowest level of abstraction, and so C has robust support for it.

PHP was intended to make dynamic web page content as flexible and painless as possible.  This is quite a few steps removed from the super-low level of the C world; managing memory is, for the purposes PHP is intended to address, much too low level to be of much interest.  Any kind of automatic memory management would be fine, so long as it is robust and reliable, and stays out of the way.  That's exactly the situation you see in PHP; objects are allocated automatically, when needed, and garbage collected when they are no longer useable, and it all happens without the intervention of the PHP programmer.

It's perhaps of some interest to observe that PHP is itself written in C!  the nitty gritty of memory management is written in C, which provides the tools needed to do that kind of thing, so that the language created, doesn't require the programmer to do much themselves.

Comment: According to Lerdorf PHP was designed for non-programmers. And that is obviously the root of all evil. It is a contradictory design goal which leads to oversimplification and in turn to more complexity. Face it: using a programming language makes you a programmer. Imagine a car designed for non-drivers. Imagine surgeon tools designed for non-surgeons.

Comment: @ThomasX, while I don't want to leap robustly to the defence of PHP or anything, isn't a fairer analogy "a car designed for non-mechanics"?  That car is still occasionally going to break down and cost you a packet, of course...

Comment: I do agree that some of the simplicity can lead to a ratking of code, but just because it's easy to write bad code doesn't mean it's hard to write good code. RoR is adamant about duck-typing, and everyone sucks their ruby balls. PHP does type juggling and everyone snickers and acts like it's coding for retards and housewives. Jquery could be called "javascript for people who don't want to deal with javascript's bullshit" but that doesn't make it a contradictory design, it makes it the best thing to happen to browser-side code. It makes it smarter.

Answer (score 13):

You actually can't do the same things in PHP, if it concerns actual (physical, not pretend virtual) hardware and/or video bitmaps (etc.) at fixed non-remapped physical addresses, perhaps in some constrained number of CPU cycles.

Web sites are not the only things run by software.

Comment: +1 for "Web sites are not the only things run by software". A lot of people seem to think that software development is always web development...

Comment: And php is not only used for web dev tho. A lot of people seem to think that php is for web only...

Answer (score 5):

PHP is actually an extremely limited language.  It can do one thing well--produce webpages--because it was only ever designed to do that one thing.  But if you wanted to build a 3D game, or write an operating system, or create a competitor to Photoshop, you wouldn't want to do that in PHP!

C, on the other hand, is a general-purpose language.  It was first designed to build operating systems, which provide an interface between the hardware and the rest of the software.  To do that, you need a concept of direct memory access.  (For example, if you want to send something to a printer, you need to be able to send data over a network, you need to be able to write directly to the location in memory where the network hardware's input buffer is located.)  That's what pointers are really for.

The problem with pointers in C, and the thing that makes them difficult to understand, is that in C they're used as a "magic hammer".  Earlier languages had better ways to do certain things that in C are only available by using pointers.  (FORTRAN had pass-by-reference, and ALGOL and Pascal had real arrays, for example.  C has neither; you have to fake both by abusing pointers.)  Since they're used all over the place for many different things that can and should be done other ways, it makes it difficult to understand what they're about.

Comment: What's not "real" about a C array?  True, when passed into a function (or assigned) they turn into pointers, but when declared, I think they qualify as a "real" array... just allocated on the stack.

Comment: @JoelFan: not only they're as real as any other, but (re)implementing them with pointers isn't 'fake' nor 'abusing pointers'.  It's how these things are done.

Comment: @Mason Wheeler: "things that can and should be done other ways".  which other ways? references are pointers hidden by syntax, arrays are handled by memory indirections (lower level name for pointers).  This is how computers work, if you don't like it then just use higher level languages and ignore the man behind the curtain.  There's no shame on prefering higher abstractions, but don't try to convince that the foundations are somehow 'flawed'.

Comment: @Javier: References are more than "pointers hidden by syntax", they're a definition that provides a greater degree of expressive power, and eliminates bugs caused by confusion. If you have a C function that takes an argument `int *value`, is that an integer-by-reference or is it an array of integers? You don't know without examining the code, which can be non-trivial. (Don't even try saying "documentation." Docs can be wrong, and frequently are.) Whereas in Pascal, if you have a parameter declared as `var value: integer`, you know that's a single integer by reference. No confusion is possible.

Comment: @JoelFan: C does not have real arrays, because real arrays have bounds. Even ignoring the "they turn into pointers when you pass them" issue, let's say you allocate `int myArray[6];` on the stack. You can then, in the same function, write to or read from `myArray[28]` and that's perfectly legal to the C language. (You can also access `[myArray]28` with the same result!) This is because C does not have arrays; it has pointers dressed up in ALGOL array syntax to make them look like arrays. If it did, the Morris Worm infection (and thousands of hacks like it since then) would never have happened.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: i agree that a reference syntax can make intention more obvious, self-documenting in the best case; but it's still a pointer with different syntax. no more, no less.   My point isn't that since those things are made with pointers then you don't need them; is that precisely their power rely on the pointers underneath.

Comment: *"allocate `int myArray[6];` on the stack ... [You can] write to or read from `myArray[28]` and that's perfectly legal to the C language"* Actually, it's not. But that won't prevent the compiler from compiling an illegal program.

Comment: @trinithis: That makes no sense.  For all practical purposes, the compiler defines what is and is not a legal program.  Rejecting illegal code (generating errors) is one of the most significant parts of its job.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: Then you are compiling a language similar to C, but not C. That is, you have a compiler for a C-like language that also compiles C. In fact, for the general case, a C compiler cannot reject all illegal C programs. Solving this would solve the halting problem.

Comment: @trinthis: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you mean by that.  *Legal code (for any language) is exactly what the compiler will accept, nothing more, nothing less.*  Are you talking about some "platonic ideal C" that's supposed to reject that?  Does the standard say the compiler is supposed to reject that, and it's just that no one has ever implemented the standard right?  The problem here is that the example array code I showed is *nonsensical,* it's *trivially obvious that it's not correct*, but it is still *100% legal C code*.

Comment: Alright then: You do not have a 100% conformant C compiler (let's fix our version of C to whatever, such as C99... doesn't matter). I'm saying it is impossible to create a 100% conformant C compiler. I'm just being pendantic.

Comment: @trinithis: So does (any version of) the C language spec state that that should not be accepted by the compiler?  I'm looking for verifiable facts here, not claims.  Everything I've said, you can test with any common C compiler.  Can you point to a language spec that says they're all wrong?

Comment: @MasonWheeler: Attempting to access an element outside the bounds of an array *isn't* "perfectly legal"; however, the language standard leaves the behavior on doing so *undefined*, so implementations can handle the situation any way they want to.  If you *want* to build an implementation that throws an exception if it detects an out-of-bounds array access, feel free to do so.  Just realize that it's a bugger to detect in the general case.

Comment: Chapter and verse: 6.5.6/8: "When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the
result has the type of the pointer operand...If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined**."

Comment: @JohnBode: It's not hard at all to detect in the general case, if you aren't chained to a requirement to be backwards-compatible with existing C code.  Because it's impossible without a type system at the language-level that recognizes the concept of an array as its own fundamental entity, and you can't graft that onto C without breaking the language. You get about 90% of it with Delphi, though there are still ways overrun the bounds of an array if you circumvent the type system. But they're rare. In a managed language that enforces type-safe code, you can eliminate buffer overruns altogether.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: It's difficult to detect in the general case **in C** because of C's array and pointer semantics.  Java's array semantics are different.

Answer (score 3):

Yes to all of the above. But there are other things to consider.

```
(type *T) list ~ (type T) list[]  // pointer can be used as an alias for an array
```

The only difference is that an array is a constant pointer, meaning it cannot be reassigned to point to something else. And,

```
*(list + n) = list[n].
```

To sort a list, especially a multidimensional one, it *is more efficient* to just move the pointers around. There is no need to copy and drag data around.

What (* = deference) means depends on context. Pointers are always declared using it,
e.g. `char *p`, `int *n`, `struct record *rec`.

In a statement (*) returns the value pointed to.
Thus.

```
char ch = *p;   // ch = value p is currently pointing at.
```

In C++ you can use pointers to get base class data or methods from a derived class, provided that the classes are properly defined.

Certainly, the understanding of pointers takes time, but necessity often facilitates
imaginative uses.

Contrast this with PHP which is an primarily designed to be a *back end*
language. Although it can be sophisticated in implementation, it was not designed for
robust computing.

Answer (score 2):

C is a systems programming language, which can be used to create things like device drivers, embedded software and operating systems.

PHP is a scripting language used to create websites.

They're not the same thing at all.  Apples and oranges.

It is not true that both languages have the same syntax.  The C language requires that variables be explicitly declared.  PHP deduces a variable's type from its usage. Parameter passing is different.  Rules about variable scope are different.  There are some syntactical similarities, but it's not true that they use the same syntax.

Address oriented operations (which are enabled by the availability of pointers) are required by many low level tasks that the C language is used for.

Comment: Creating websites is a very common use for PHP, but it's certainly not the only one.

Comment: Understood - but writing device drivers is *not* a use for PHP either, hence the lack of pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Pointers in C serve three main purposes:

**Faking pass-by-reference**

C passes all function arguments by value; the formal parameters and the actual parameters are different objects in memory, so changes to the formal parameter are not reflected in the actual parameter.  If you want a function to change the value of something in the caller, you must pass the pointer to that object:

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
  int tmp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = tmp;
}

int main(void)
{
  int x = 3, y = 4;
  swap(&x, &y);
  return 0;
}
```

The *expressions* `*a` and `*b` in `swap` correspond to the objects `x` and `y` in `main`, so writing to `*a` updates `x` and writing to `*b` updates `y`.

**Tracking dynamically allocated memory**

The C memory allocation functions `malloc`, `calloc`, and `realloc` all return pointers to the first element of the dynamically allocated buffer.

```
int *arr = malloc(sizeof *arr * N); // allocates a block of memory large
                                    // enough to hold N ints
```

You can apply the subscript operator to a pointer *as though* it were an array (the subscript operation `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a + i)`; that is, offset `i` elements from `a` and dereference the result).

**Building self-referential data structures**

Although generations of Fortran programmers were building lists, trees, queues, stacks, etc., without them, pointers make building self-referential structures very easy, such as this binary tree node:

```
struct tnode {
  K key;                // for some arbitrary type K
  T data;               // for some arbitrary type T
  struct tnode *left;   // explicitly points to left subtree
  struct tnode *right;  // explicitly points to right subtree
};
```

I'm not familiar enough with PHP to say how you would do these things in that language.  I would point out that C predates PHP by at least a couple of decades, and that PHP is pretty specific to a particular domain.

As to why C doesn't handle all this automagically...

One of the guiding philosophies of C is to keep the language as simple as possible, making it relatively easy to implement.  Automatic memory management would add some complexity to the language (adding the threading library in C11 certainly did).  Not to mention that automatic memory management can also play hell with performance-critical code.

Answer (score 1):

PHP does allow you to use pointers, as you can see in the official documentation on [References](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php#language.references.whatdo.assign).

It's not exactly the same thing as in C, as the latter does allow you to allocate memory very precisely, but pointers are present in a lot of language.

Basically, remember that every time that you create an array or a class in an object-oriented language (C++, C#, Java, ...) you actually create a pointer that is stored in the variable. What allows you to skip the `*` operators is some kind of synthaxic sugar.

Comment: that page links to.. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.arent.php

Comment: They are not exactly pointers, as I explain later you can do deeper things in C. But one of the main goal of pointer is to be able to pass arguments to function by reference. And that's exactly what is said in the doc.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish much of the functionality of pointers by using integer operations on an array index. This integer index is often called a *cursor*.

Instead of manipulating a pointer value `char *p`, you manipulate the cursor `int i` and index the array `arr[i]` to yield the value in that memory cell.

To some extent, this is just putting fancy names on obvious facts. But having names lends credibility to a valid technique that may be easily overlooked. :)

The real advantage is that familiarity with this allows you to translate code using pointers into languages that don't have them.

Answer (score 0):

C is a pretty low level language, it's pretty much one step removed from Assembly (and C was designed to be a portable assembly). It's an abstraction of the machine, and uses pointers because it allows you to operate at the machine level, and back then you would use pointers to directly access memory (virtual memory has made this practice mostly arcane).

Note that C was created in the 70s, when computers were far simpler than they were now, and direct memory addressing was how software worked. Pointers are also used for things like arrays (you could say arrays are syntactic sugar for pointers in C), and dynamic memory allocation to create data whose size may be unknown at compile time.

PHP is much newer than C (late 90s) and is heavily influenced by C in its design, but it, like many other languages newer than C, abstracts away raw pointer usage and instead uses things like [References](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatare.php), which are like limited pointer, in that they can refer to other data, but you can not do things like perform pointer arithmetic, nor do they represent addresses.

PHP was designed to be easy for people to learn, and a pain point many programmers have when using C (or C++) is pointers, so PHP and many other languages abstract away pointers and use references, objects, implicit heap allocation, etc. to hide pointer usage from you. Internally, PHP will be using pointers (it is written in C, after all), but you yourself do not have to be concerned about that.

As for complicating C? I think C is a rather simple language (the de facto book is 300 pages and shorter than most other language books), but pointers do take some mental work to understand.

Comment: virtual memory doesn't diminish pointers importance a bit.